# Is it legal to crawl a brands Instagram image and products and tag their products onto their images?

Tags: copyright

Im a developer and almost finished an app. Im at a crossroad though and don't want to get sued.

Is it legal to do the following.

1) Crawl a brands Instagram page like https://www.instagram.com/citybeachaustralia/ and crate a profile on my app like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

This is illegal for at least four different reasons.

Your crawling [violates the TOS](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23935/how-can-sites-like-https-www-brandwatch-com-crawl-instagram-legally) as you explained yourself in another question at this site.

It is using a trademark of the company in connection with merchandise to sell that merchandise without their authorization in a manner that would not constitute nominative use of the trademark.

It also uses their copyrighted advertising material, without their permission, for no purpose and in no manner that would seem to constitute fair use of a copyright.

It also commercially appropriates the image of the models without permission from the model for you to use their images.

You should put the app in a portfolio to show your IT knowledge when you apply for an app coding job and you should never actually use it.